# I can't get the driver.get() to open a website on neither safari nor chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, safari, automated-tests

So I'm just starting to learn selenium on my MacBook. In class, my teacher uses a windows laptop and chrome to open the code, but I was having difficulty getting ChromeDriver to work and open Chrome, so I tried using safari because it's a lot easier to set up. I installed python, got everything downloaded, am on Mac OS 11.5.2, have Safari 14.1.2 (16611.3.10.1.6) and the selenium with it. I tried running this code:

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   import time

   driver = webdriver.Safari()
   driver.get('google.com')
   time.sleep(5)

   driver.close()
```

in a file called test.py, and it opens safari but doesn't go to the website. I then proceeded to get ChromeDriver, put it in usr/local/bin, because for the life of me, I couldn't get it to open chrome if I changed the code to webdriver.Chrome() but again, it opens chrome yet doesn't go to the link. I am losing my mind. Does anyone have any idea on what's wrong? My teacher was able to open it using this code so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the configuration your teacher is using. However with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) you can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.safari.service import Service

s = Service('/usr/bin/safaridriver')
driver = webdriver.Safari(service=s)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Ensure that:

- If you are using ***safari version 12*** or later and Mac version ***High Sierra*** or later just make sure Safari’s executable is located at `/usr/bin/safaridriver`
- Run once `safaridriver --enable` in terminal and start running selenium scripts os safari.